# zlib - data format compatibility among different zlib versions

Tags: zlib

I am using zlib version 1.2.3 and compressing data with compress2().
The compressed data is sent to another computer where the data is to be uncompressed.
Are there any version incompatibility issues with zlib?
I perform compress2() with zlib version 1.2.3 on computer 1 and uncompress() it with probably a higher version of zlib on computer 2.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no version incompatibility issues, forward or back.